# Implementing "Night Mode" in GIS with WMS

Tags: maps, gis, openstreetmap, arcgis, qgis

I am fairly new to the world of developing and the world of mapping. For my studies I want to implement a WMS map into QGIS/ArcGIS but have it in a night mode/dark mode style for better visual representation. Now as I looked through the web, I did not find a service or provider who has a WMS server with a night mode OSM (Open street map). Does somebody of you have an idea on how to solve this problem? Maybe even with a python code?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This question is offtopic for StackOverflow. Try https://gis.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using leaflet in JS or QGIS for example you can use xyz tiles. [Here](http://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/) you can find some examples.

For QGIS, get the link that looks like 'https://example.com/{z}/{x}/{y}.png' in the plane JavaScript code snippet in the website and add a new xyz connection.